# correct way to listen/react to particular actions on a redux application

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm writing my first redux application using Angular and ngrx. In several occasions I found myself in doubt on how to correctly "concatenate" a series of actions. I make an example.

My app has a customer list panel and a customer detail panel, when the user select a specific customer I want the detail panel to display the customer info but also I want to hide the customer list panel.

Currently I'm dispatching an `CustomerSelected` action which triggers an effect (a side effect) which loads the customer details from the server. When the details are loaded I dispatch a `CusomerDetailLoaded` action which updates the store with the customer information. It also triggers an effect which dispatch a `HideCustomerList` action which hides the customer list panel.

Is this acceptable or there are better ways to achieve this? In particular I feel like the `CustomerDetailLoaded` is now tightly coupled with a layout detail, all the times we load a customer detail we also hide the customer list panel... sounds like a mistake to me.

Thanks,
Gab

Comment: Not familiar with Angular or ngrx really, but in the React+Redux world you could do this "cleaner" in mapDispatchToProps. This is the right place whenever you need several actions to happen at once, which are otherwise unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redux-observable` library provides nice way to listen specific actions and dispatch another actions after.

For example, if you want to dispatch `ACTION_B` after `ACTION_A`, you can do something like this:

```js
const rootEpic = (action$) => action$.ofType('ACTION_A').mapTo({
  type: 'ACTION_B'
});
```

Next, if you want to dispatch `ACTION_C` after `ACTION_B`, you could use `combineEpics` helper:

```js
const epicA = (action$) => action$.ofType('ACTION_A').mapTo({
  type: 'ACTION_B'
});
const epicB = (action$) => action$.ofType('ACTION_B').mapTo({
  type: 'ACTION_C'
});
const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  epicA,
  epicB
)
```

Take a look at their [documentation](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html) for further info.

Comment: redux-observable seems very similar to ngrx effects https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/effects. So it seems like effects is the right place to manage these kind of sequences of actions.